# Does DVD has 2 lasers?

Tags: dvd

I dismantled my DVD and in laser module I see main laser on the top and something on the side which looks similar. Do you know what can it be?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, a DVD drive only has one laser module. I am guessing you have mistaken a lens as the other.

If I have got this wrong or you are sure it is an entire module, please post a picture and il try to identify it.